# What does the user need to run a WPF browser application?

Tags: .net, wpf, browser

I've been developing on WinForms and WebForms since the last 4 years. I didn't consider migration to WPF till now, but I am considering it now. Please tell me what's required at the client end to properly run WPF applications in the browser. What are the platforms it's compatible with?

Does the user need to install any special plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN:

> To run a WPF application, the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework must be
>   installed on the client. Internet
>   Explorer 7 automatically detects
>   whether clients are installed with
>   .NET Framework when WPF browser-hosted
>   applications are browsed. If not
>   installed, Internet Explorer 7 prompts
>   users to install it.
>
> To detect whether .NET Framework is
>   installed, Internet Explorer 7
>   includes a bootstrapper application
>   that is registered as the fallback
>   Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions
>   (MIME) handler for content files with
>   the following extensions: .xaml, .xps,
>   .xbap, and .application. When these
>   file types are navigated to, and the
>   .NET Framework is not installed on the
>   client, the bootstrapper application
>   asks for permission to install it. If
>   permission is not provided, neither
>   the .NET Framework nor the application
>   is installed.
>
> If permission is granted, Internet
>   Explorer 7 downloads and installs the
>   .NET Framework using the Microsoft
>   Background Intelligent Transfer
>   Service (BITS). After successful
>   installation of the .NET Framework,
>   the originally requested file is
>   launched in a new browser window.
>
> .NET Framework auto-detection is
>   available on Windows Vista, Microsoft
>   Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2), and
>   Microsoft Windows Server 2003 (SP1)
>   clients that have Internet Explorer 7
>   installed.

I think your audience for a WPF browser application might be somewhat limited at this time.

Answer (score 1):

On the client, you'll need the 3.5 version of the .net framework installed and IE6+ or Firefox.